# Calling generic method using reflection in .NET

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

I have a question. Is it possible to call generic method using reflection in .NET?
I tried the following code

```
var service = new ServiceClass();
Type serviceType = service.GetType();
MethodInfo method = serviceType.GetMethod("Method1", new Type[]{});
method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass));
var result = method.Invoke(service, null);
```

But it throws the following exception "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true."

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You're not using the result of `MakeGenericMethod` - which doesn't change the method you call it on; it returns another object representing the constructed method. You should have something like:

```
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass));
var result = method.Invoke(service, null);
```

(or use a different variable, of course).

Comment: I had the same exact problem of not realizing that `MakeGenericMethod` is a function, not a void method, I'm sure it was ha_t's issue as well.

Comment: I just made the same mistake but it was because I inserted the line to assign the result of MakeGenericMethod but forgot to change the invoking code to use that new returned value.

Comment: is it bad for performance ? if i have this piece of code for every byte array I receive to deserializse  from ? I am using a library that i can not change, but would like to use in my project for dynamically creating those class definitions that serializer library expects !! I am able to do it but not sure if this is worth the effort,

Comment: @kuldeep: You should benchmark your code to find out the impact. It would be foolish of me to make a prediction about the impact without knowing a lot more about your system.

Answer (score 11):

You need to say

```
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass));
```

at a minumum and preferably

```
var constructedMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass));
constructedMethod.Invoke(service, null);
```

as instances of `MethodInfo` are immutable.

This is the same concept as

```
string s = "Foo ";
s.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
string t = s.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(t.Length);
```

causing

```
4
3
```

to print on the console.

By the way, your error message

> "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which `ContainsGenericParameters` is `true`."

if your clue that `method` still contains generic parameters.